# How-to override KeyPressEvent for an editable QComboBox?

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, qcombobox

I have a class named `ValidableComboBox` that derives directly from `QComboBox`.

Every instance of `ValidableComboBox` has `setEditable()` set to `true`. My goal is to add some signal that will be emitted whenever someone presses return key in the `QComboBox`.

To do so, I reimplemented `void KeyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e)` in `ValidableComboBox`. However, it seems that it never gets called when I type something into the combobox.

Is there a way to achieve this ? What could possibly be wrong with what I have done ?

Thank you.

Comment: Stupid question but it happened to me once: you've reimplemented the keyPressEvent as a virtual function, right?  That could be it.  And, it seems you have a capital K in your question, in your code is it a small k?

Comment: @Gianni: I got a capital `K`... I hate myself :P If you add this as an answer, I will accept it ;) Many thanks ! I thought of a lot of things, but that... I really need some time off :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The funktion you've seem to be using in your kode has a Kapital K, instead of a small k, ok?  :-D