# How Call the KeyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *) of linedit of QCombobox?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QComboBox`, which is editable, I implemented the `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *)` method, but it does not seem to fire this method.

I can think of the only reason this happens is that **whatever editing that occurs is actually happening in lineEdit object and We should implement keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *) of line Edit**. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How-to override KeyPressEvent for an editable QComboBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264795/how-to-override-keypressevent-for-an-editable-qcombobox)

Comment: I have implemented the keyPressEvent method and I had no problems, you could show what you tried.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you think you need to reimplement the `keyPressEvent`?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Install an event filter on the `lineEdit` widget.
2. Use `setLineEdit` to replace the existing widget with your own subclass that reimplements the event handler.

Comment: I tried installing event filter but its not working.

Comment: That's not enough information. Please show your work. Edit the question to offer a self-contained `main.cpp` that demonstrates the issue. Ensure that it is truly minimal. Think 40-50 lines at most. Begin the file with `#include <QtWidgets>`, end with `#include "main.moc"`.